# Calculate the total size of a List<String[]> converted to a CSV

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv, java-stream

I have a list of `List<String[]> csvRows, String[] csvHeaderRow`

My goal is to calculate the total size of the final CSV file I would write out of these rows. So I should add the total size of all commas, `csvRows`, `csvHeaderRow`. Note that, a lot of columns in `csvRows` could be null of empty like `"Rick,,,,15,,4324,,,"`.  `csvHeaderRow` will always be populated fully.

I can write these all to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and calculate the length of the byte array. But I want to write more performant, and concise code.

Latest code version:

```java
public void long getNumOfFiles(List<String[]> csvRows, String[] csvHeaderRow){
    long totalSize = csvRows.stream().mapToLong(i -> {
            return Stream.of(i).mapToLong(str -> {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(str)) {
                    return str.getBytes().length;
                }
                return 0L;
            }).sum();
        }).sum();
        
                totalSize = totalSize + Stream.of(csvHeaderRow).mapToLong(str -> str.getBytes().length).sum();
                totalSize = totalSize + csvHeaderRow.length * csvRows.size() + 1; -> number of commas
                long numOfFiles = (totalSize / MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES) + 1;
    return numOfFiles;
}
```

How do I write this more efficiently?

Comment: More performant compared to what? Are you having any issues with the performance?

Comment: as opposed to the following. My dataset could have millions of rows, so even though I have not seen any performance issues yet with my tiny 1000 row dataset, I am wondering if I would see eventually whne I do stress and performance testing later: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        out.writeObject(csvRows);
        out.close();
        long size = baos.toByteArray().length;
        long filesNum = (size / MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES) + 1;

Comment: Do the stress testing first, compare versions and analyze results to identify issues. Premature optimization is a bad practice.

Comment: have scheduled that with the performance team in the next couple weeks. But I dont see whats wrong in identifying potential issues and trying to address them. looking at the two options the bytearrayOutputstream will obviously take more memory, and time compared to simple length calculation

Comment: What is `(totalSize / MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES) + 1` for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your algorithm is correct, but the following is a simpler `Stream` solution that returns an equivalent result:

```java
long totalSize = Stream.concat(
                Stream.<String[]>of(csvHeaderRow), csvRows.stream())
        .mapToLong(row ->
                Arrays.stream(row)
                        .mapToInt(s -> s == null ? 0 : s.getBytes().length)
                        .sum()
                + row.length - 1)
        .sum();
totalSize += 1;
return totalSize / MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES + 1;
```

The following solution isn't identical to yours, but I think gives the actual correct result (though I'm not sure what that `MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES` division is):

```java
long totalSize = Stream.concat(
                Stream.<String[]>of(csvHeaderRow), csvRows.stream())
        .mapToLong(row ->
                // Number of characters per row, plus one for each comma
                Arrays.stream(row)
                        .mapToInt(s -> s == null ? 0 : s.getBytes().length)
                        .sum()
                + row.length - 1)
        .sum();
totalSize += csvRows.size() + 1; // Add number of newlines (incl. trailing one)
return totalSize / MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES + 1; // Whatever this is
```